# Info from loadData in JavaScript is not appearing in my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that should submit a request to the open movie database and return the movies.  But it isn't returning anything and it seems as though loadData isn't even working. Because $greeting.text('So, you want to search for ' + movieStr); isn't working either. It should show So you want to search for in the html and it doesn't appear. If go directly to www.omdbapi.com/?t=fall it returns a json.

```js
 function loadData(){

 var $movieElem = $('movie-items');
 var $greeting = $('#greeting');

 $movieElem.text("");



 var movieStr = $('#movie').val();
 var omdbapiUrl = 'www.omdbapi.com/?t='+ movieStr;

 $greeting.text('So, you want to search for ' + movieStr);


 $.getJSON(omdbapiUrl, function(data){

  items = data.response.docs;

  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
   var item = items[i];
   $movieElem.append('<li>'+ '<p>' + item.Title + '<p>' +'<p>' + item.Director + '</p>'+'</li>');


  };
 }).error(function(e)){

 });
$('#form-container').submit(loadData);
}
```

```html
    <form id="form-container" class="form-container">

    <label for="movie">Movie:</label><input type="text" id="movie" value=""><br>
    <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>

    </form>

    <h2 id="greeting">What do you want to search for? </h2>

    <ul id="movie-items"> Movie info will appear here</ul>
```

Thanks for the suggestion. I modified my code and it still isn't showing anything. I think the primary issue is that loadData isn't being called because nothing is appearing in the console.log when I added a console.log statement from within loadData. Is there something wrong with this line that is loading the data?   I don't see any errors in the console.log

```
$('#form-container').submit(loadData);
```

This is from the html

```
<form id="form-container" class="form-container">
```

This isn't showing anything in the console.log

```
console.log("Hello from loadData");
```

This is script.js

```
function loadData(){

console.log("Hello from loadData");

var $movieElem = $('movie-items');
var $greeting = $('#greeting');

$movieElem.text("");



var movieStr = $('#movie').val();


$greeting.text('So, you want to search for ' + movieStr);


var omdbapiUrl = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=fall';

$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON(omdbapiUrl, function(data){
  console.log(data);
}).error(function(e){

});
  });
$('#form-container').submit(loadData);
}
```

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>


</head>

<body>
<form id="form-container" class="form-container">

<label for="movie">Movie:</label><input type="text" id="movie" value=""><br>
<button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>

</form>

<h2 id="greeting">What do you want to search for? </h2>

<ul id="movie-items"> Movie info will appear here</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see my latest edit. You have everything inside a function that you are not calling. See my code to identify the error. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Us the example bellow. You are adding an extra parenthesis and you are missing the http: for external calls

**the problem:** .error(function(e)**)**{

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 function loadData(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Hello from loadData");

  var $movieElem = $('movie-items');
  var $greeting = $('#greeting');

  $movieElem.text("");



  var movieStr = $('#movie').val();


  $greeting.text('So, you want to search for ' + movieStr);


  var omdbapiUrl = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=fall';

  $.getJSON(omdbapiUrl, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
   }).error(function(e) {

   });
  
 }
 $('#form-container').submit(loadData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>


</head>

<body>
<form id="form-container" class="form-container">

<label for="movie">Movie:</label><input type="text" id="movie" value=""><br>
<button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>

</form>

<h2 id="greeting">What do you want to search for? </h2>

<ul id="movie-items"> Movie info will appear here</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it still doesn't work. I think the problem is that my function isn't being called at all for some reason. Because I added console.log("Hello inside loadData function" ) and it doesn't print out anything in the console. I think I am limited in this comment section to post my code here so I will post below.

Comment: is your whole js code wrapped inside a $(document).ready(function() {

});
also correct the problem that i pointed before

Comment: I changed it to removed the additional ) as you suggested and added in the http. I don't think the http was the problem though because it wasn't working before when I had that there. I think still is that my loadData function isn't being called but I don't understand why. I will try to move the javascript code out of my javascript file and into my html file and remove all the extra stuff that I don't need.

Comment: see my latest edit. You have everything inside a function that you are not calling. See my code to identify the error. ;)

Comment: I have removed things from script.js that weren't necessary and removed the function loadData() and just put in the stuff you suggested. I didn't understand before I only needed that not the other stuff. Now I don't see anything appearing in my html page but the json data is appearing in my console.log So I think I just need to get the data to appear in my html. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ok. I understand. I didn't need the things inside the function which I thought I was calling but apparently not. It is returning the stuff now. Thanks again for responding so quickly and so many times!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove all the extra stuff in my script.js file that wasn't needed and wasn't being called and just leave Panagiotis Vrs's code.

```
var omdbapiUrl = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=fall';

$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON(omdbapiUrl, function(data){
  console.log(data);
}).error(function(e){

});
});
```

EDIT:

I have used Panagiotis Vr's code to instead wrap everything in a document.ready as mentioned in the below post.

Comment: you can just press the top arrow on my solution and leave it as the one that fixed your problem. ;) have fun with your project. cheers

Comment: Thanks I pressed the up button but it said that it didn't changed the recorded score because I have less than fifteen feedback. But thanks so much for your help.